# cnn classifier failing on image after contour selecting

Tags: image-classification, cnn

I have a trained mnist-based cnn classifier which is working fine when there is only one number in the image.For more than 1 number in the image I am taking contours and separating the numbers using ROI.
But my model is failing on the separated images
Original image
[image]

Contoured image
[image]

Here 5 is being classified as 3.
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("im1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # grayscale
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(thresh1, 11, 17, 17)
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
img_erosion = cv2.erode(img_dilation, kernel, iterations=1)
#edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
plt.imshow(img_erosion[:,:], 'gray')
im2,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_erosion.copy(),         cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
# get contours
# for each contour found, draw a rectangle around it on original image
roi=[]
i=0
for contour in contours:

    # get rectangle bounding contour

    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
# discard areas that are too large

    if h>300 and w>300:

        continue
# discard areas that are too small

    if h<40 or w<40:

        continue
# draw rectangle around contour on original image
    i=i+1
    roi.append(image[y:y+h, x:x+w])
#cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)
# write original image with added contours to disk  
im_names=["im1.png","im2.png","im3.png"]
i=0
"""for roi in roi:
    cv2.imwrite(im_names[i], roi)
    i=i+1"""
str1=''
for roi in roi:

   #im = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
    #cv2.imwrite("contoured.png", image)
    im=roi
    from skimage.transform import resize

    def rgb2gray(rgb):
        return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

    #im = plt.imread("contoured.png")
    im = rgb2gray(im)
    im = resize(im, (28, 28))

    plt.imshow(im[:,:], 'gray')
    #plt.show()

    temp = np.zeros((1,28,28,1))
    temp[0,:,:,0] = im
    num=int(classifier.predict_classes(temp))
    str1+=str((num))
print(str1)
```

Here classifier is the trained cnn model

Comment: Welcome to DS SE, That's just a probable case and it's absolutely normal as even humans make mistakes, you can't expect Everything from a Machine... Well here's my kernel which achieves .99+, you can try to integrate that with your work and update us...https://www.kaggle.com/adityaecdrid/mnist-with-keras-for-beginners-99457

Comment: actually this model has accuracy of 99.5%

Comment: It's normal as 3 and 5 look quite similar.., just differ at the top line direction ironically, what about other numbers?? Also having an accuracy of .995+ doesn't guarantee Everything..

Comment: Right now 5 is very close to boundary of the image.Is there some way to solve this problem

Comment: PS i don't have expertise , but I guess you should pad your images after cropping them literally...